# Check iphone app installation on device

Tags: iphone, analytics

I know unique udid/imei of devise and I need to know is this devise has installed my application.

Which mobile analytics has this information and API access to it?

Comment: Please explain more about it..

Comment: Your app (and other analytics libs) has no access to devices udid/imei

Comment: It is just my vision of this process. I want to give user unique link and check if he has installed my application.

Comment: Alexandr, there are two ways to install app to iDevice 1.You send your app to appstore, user download. 2) You build "adHoc" version for user devices (you must know IMEI before build).  It is not possible just to download and install any app to iPhone. (((